# Can one BroadcastReceiver be used for multiple IntentServices?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, listener, intentservice

Normally for a single IntentService you can define the broadcast receiver listener like this in an Activity's onCreate() method (for example)

```
broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //get stuff from the intent and do whatever you want  
    }
};
```

And you register the receiver like this (also in onCreate()):

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)
    .registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("my_intent_service"));
```

And then you start the IntentService with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyIntentService.class);
startService(intent);
```

And in the IntentService you send messages back to the receiver with:

```
Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("my_intent_service");
broadcastIntent.putExtra("whateverData", whateverData);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
```

which triggers the `onReceive` method described earlier.

And then to unregister the receivers, in onDestroy method you can do:

```
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
```

In the Manifest file, you add for your service:

```
<service
    android:name=".MyIntentService"
    android:exported="false" />
```

I want to receive broadcasts from multiple IntentServices in the same Activity.

Do you need one receiver per IntentService? As in, if I make `n` IntentServices do I need to register `n` receivers, make `n` listener, and unregister `n` receivers in onDestroy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes you can use one broadcast receiver in one activity, that would handle multiple intents from different services.
I’d recommend to add multiple intent-filter to your broadcast receiver to make distinction from which Service you are getting a broadcast.

Answer (score 6):

The way to filter multiple `actions` with one `BroadcastReceiver` is to add them to the IntentFilter:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction("my_intent_service1"); // Action1 to filter
intentFilter.addAction("my_intent_service2"); // Action2 to filter
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
```

And in your `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("my_intent_service1")) {
            // Action 1
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals("my_intent_service2")) {
            // Action 2
        }
    }
};
```